# Replicating a java object(not part of a session) between 2 tomcat instances

Tags: tomcat, replication

Is it possible to replicate any serializable java object between two tomcat instances that are part of a cluster.I have tested session replication and tried adding serializable objects session attributes.That works fine, but I am trying to figure out if there is a way to replicate a java object between 2 tomcat instances that is not part of a session.

Thanks .

Comment: Would it be helpful if some attributes in the `ServletContext` were replicated for you across the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Your options include anything from [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html), through [jax-ws SOAP](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) or [jax-rs REST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp1v/index.html) web services.

Please read any of the above links, see if they match your use case, and post a new query if you have any specific questions about programming any of these technologies.

You might even want to look at [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html):

- [How to Deploy Spring Application in Tomcat](http://www.dailyrazor.com/blog/how-to-deploy-spring-application-in-tomcat/)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is very similar to keeping such objects in a session is to keep them in a cache, but use caching software that supports a distributed cache. That way, the caching software will be the one using TCP/IP or some higher-level protocol to communicate with its siblings, and you just need to configure it.

You could "roll your own" way in which nodes communicate, but there's listen reason to do so.